# How to disable RawMaterialButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

There is a butoon defined as

```
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const RoundIconButton({required this.icon, required this.onPressed});
  final IconData icon;
  final Function? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: () => onPressed,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
    );
  }
}
```

and usage

```
RoundIconButton(
    icon: Icons.arrow_forward,
    onPressed: null,
),
```

Despite I pass null into onPress the button is still clicable, how to disable it preventing clicable ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onPressed` in RawMaterialButton like this.

```dart
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const RoundIconButton({required this.icon, required this.onPressed});
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed; // Change like this

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed, // Change like this
      shape: CircleBorder(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first null or not.

```
onPressed: () => onPressed == null ? () {} : this.onPressed,
```

Let me know it does work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Do this

```
 class _ButtonDisableState extends State<ButtonDisable> {

 bool isEnabled = true;

 void ButtonClicked(){
    setState(() {
        isEnabled=false;
        print("Clicked Once");
     }); 
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
              child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                         RawMaterialButton(onPressed: (){
                                    if(isEnabled)
                                    {
                                      ButtonClicked();
                                    }
                            },child: Text('Click',style: TextStyle(color: 
                          Colors.white,)),fillColor: Colors.black,)
                 ],
             ),
           ),
         );
       }
     }
```

Result, The Button will be clickable until the variable isEnable = true, if it false the button will do nothing.

[image]

Output: I/flutter (13110): Clicked Once

**Example 2**
If you want to make the button InVisibility, then just make use of Visibility Widget and user property visible : true / false

```
Visibility(
          visible: isEnabled,
          child: RawMaterialButton(onPressed: (){
            if(isEnabled)
              {
                ButtonClicked();
              }
          },child: Text('Click',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),fillColor: 
        Colors.black,),
        ),
```